# Java Looping through 2D array - Homework

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have to loop through a 2D array, create and store a random question, and test the user's response. However, I can't figure out how to properly reference the elements. I'm use to the old syntax of (counter; counter < x; counter++).

How do I reference a specific array element with this syntax? It's quite confusing to me. I need to reference the 5th element in the row to see what the user entered to break from the loop and also to loop through and transpose a 1D array into the 2D array's current row.

```
    for(int arrRow[] : arr)                 //arr is a [100][5] array
    {
        switch(rNum.nextInt(4))             //Creates a random number between 0 and 3 and passes it to a switch statement
        {
            case 0:                         //Generates an Addition question
                arr2 = a.quiz();
                break;
            case 1:                         //Generates a Subtraction question
                arr2 = s.quiz();
                break;
            case 2:                         //Generates a Multiplication question
                arr2 = m.quiz();
                break;
            case 3:                         //Generates a Division question
                arr2 = d.quiz();
        }

        //for (colNum=0; colNum<5;colNum++) //loops through the column in the 2D array and pulls data from returned array
        for(int arrCol : arrRow)
        {
            arrCol = arr2[arrCol];
        }

        if(arrRow[4] == -1)                 //If user enters a -1, breaks from the for loop
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    newTest.printQuestionResult();          //Calls the print function after the user is done or the test is complete
}
```

Comment: You do not need `arrCol = arr2[arrCol];`  The code `for(int arrCol : arrRow)` already assigns the value to `arrCol`

Comment: What's `arr2` supposed to contain? And what values do `arrCol` hold that made it the index of `arr2`? What is clear is `arrCol = arr2[arrCol];` is definitely wrong as you are assigning a primitive variable (referenced by value) with new value, which wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Consider your 2D Array like a Data Table that contains 100 Rows (y) with 5 Columns (x) in each Row. Iterate through your Array with that in mind: `for (int y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) { for (int x = 0; x < arr[y].length; x++) { System.out.print(arr[y][x] + "\t"); } System.out.println(""); }`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Maybe I'm not interpreting the book correctly. My understanding is that "for(arrRow[] : arr)" loops through the rows of the arr array and could be considered as arr[x], where the x value increments each time the loop runs. "for(int arrCol : arrRow)" would then loop through that row's columns. I would then interpret that arrCol would represent arr[x][y] where the y value increments each time that loop runs. Based on that, I further assume that "arrCol = arr2[arrCol]" would be the same as "arr[x][y] = arr2[y]".

Comment: @DevilsHnd - Thanks for that tip. I can get it to work that way no problem, but I'm really trying to understand this unfamiliar syntax from my class's assigned text. They only have a few examples in the book and I just can't seem to grasp the concept right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your `arrCol` is an `int` which is a primitive type variable, so this variable is a value copied from `arrRow`. If you assign any value to `arrCol`, it will not be reflected in `arrRow`.

You should do this instead:

```
for (int index = 0; index < arrRow.length; i++)
{
    int col = arrRow[index];
    arrRow[index] = arr2[col];
}
```

I'm not sure what `arr2` contains, so I can't be sure if you will encounter `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you read its elements like this.

I would guess that you needed `arr2[index]` rather than `arr2[col]`.

Comment: arr2 is an int array with 5 elements. the case statement calls a randomized quiz and returns a 5 element array to the arr2 array. IE - if an Addition quiz is called it could contain {1,0,2,3,4}:

1 is the left argument 
0 indicates it's an addition question
2 is the right argument
3 is the correct answer
4 is the user's response

The second for loop pulls the contents of each of arr2's elements into the current row of the main array.

If ever the user keys in a -1, it breaks from the first for loop. It works with a regular for loop, but not this new syntax I'm unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cannot use a for-each loop to alter the elements of the array as I was intending to do. I'll have to stick with the typical for loop with a counter.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/